# listening all files matching with a specific filetype and the name of the file in Groovy

Tags: file, jenkins, groovy, pipeline

Updated! thanks to @ycr

```
filesArray = []
def listFiles(def path, def filter) {
def filterBakFiles = ~/(?i)${filter}.*\.bak$/
     new File(path).traverse(type: groovy.io.FileType.FILES, nameFilter: filterBakFiles) { file ->
                        filesArray << file.name
                    }
  if (folder && filter && filesArray) {
    return filesArray
  } else if (!filesArray) {
    return ["No coincidences"]
  } else {
    return ["please enter folder and filter"]
  }
}

listFiles("\\\\networkpath\\${folder}", "${filter}")
```

this works!.
now i'm trying to fix the regex for find coincidences with numbers and text.

```
def filterBakFiles = ~/(?i)${filter}.*\.bak$/
```

best regards

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: searching by file type, for example *.bak, does not work. Additionally I want to add that it searches by name match, I don't know how to do it

Comment: Do you want to search for files recursively?

Comment: @daggett yes, thats i want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following.

```
@NonCPS
def listFiles(def path) {
     def filterBakFiles = ~/.*\.bak$/
     new File(path).traverse(type: groovy.io.FileType.FILES, nameFilter: filterBakFiles) { file ->
                        println file
                    }
}
```